# With swifter json response

Tags: swift, swift5, swifter

I am create simple rest api with swift using [swifter](https://github.com/httpswift/swifter) library
How i can response json data?

```
import Swifter

let server = HttpServer()
server["/hello"] = { request in
    var userList:[Any] = []
    for user in users {
        var b : [String: Any] = [:]
        b["name"] = user.name
        b["id"] = user.id
        userList.append(b)
    }
    return .ok(.json(userList))
}
```

But there is below error message

> Serialization error: invalidObject

---

I check the library source code, and found the error message reason

```
...
//Library Source code
    func content() -> (Int, ((HttpResponseBodyWriter) throws -> Void)?) {
        do {
            switch self {
            case .json(let object):
              guard JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(object) else {
                throw SerializationError.invalidObject
              }
              let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object)
              return (data.count, {
                try $0.write(data)
              })
...
```

So, I need pass `guard JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(object) else {`

---

also, there is no enough document for the library, How I can fix this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `codable` and a `jsonEncoder` to convert the `users` array to data and then convert them back to a jsonObject and pass it in:

```
do {
    let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
    let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(users)

    let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
    return .ok(.json(jsonObject))
} catch {
    print(error)
    return .internalServerError(.htmlBody("\(error.localizedDescription)"))
}
```

Note that you should consider returning an error to the caller of the service. I've used `.internalServerError` but you may consider returning a better error.

Comment: Thanks @Mojtaba, This is what I want

Comment: Looking into the source, it would be better to return `.ok(.data(jsonData, contentType: "application/json")))`