# swift: diction list to json

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

How i can convert diction list to json ?

```
struct User: Codable {
    var id = ""
    var deviceName = ""
}
```

```
    var userList:[Any] = []
    for user in users {
        var b : [String: Any] = [:]
        b["name"] = user.deviceName
        b["id"] = user.id
        //        b["uuid"] = user.uuid.uuidString
        userList.append(b)
        
    }
    print(JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(userList))
    
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: userList, options: .prettyPrinted)
        return .ok(.json(jsonData))
    } catch {
        return .ok(.htmlBody("Error"))
    }
```

> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__NSConcreteUUID)'
> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Or better, use `Codable` and encode users directly using `JSONEncoder`.

Comment: I am first in `Codable`, and, not good in swift

Comment: What is the `User` ?

Comment: I added `User` structure

Comment: What is a 'diction list'?

Comment: diction list means `userList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Codable` to easily encode and decode your object and JSONs:

```
do {
    let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
    let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(users)
    ,,,
} catch {
    print(error)
    return .ok(.htmlBody("\(error.localizedDescription)"))
}
```

Some side notes:

1. Always try print out the real `error` instead of throwing a simple string.
2. `Catch` means there where an error. So you may consider returning a `badRequest` or something instead of `ok`.

---

It seems like you need to pass a JSON. So you can convert the jsonData to a jsonObject like:

```
    let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
    print(JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonObject)) // <- to verify
    return .ok(.json(jsonObject))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but, `print(JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonData))` is FALSE

Comment: in the `.json` fucntion, there is `JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject`

Comment: `let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(users)` return empty data

Comment: Are you sure `users` is not empty before passing it to the decoder? I've tested the code and it works. please get rid of all side effects and test again.

Comment: if possible, could you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68414125/with-swifter-json-response ?

Comment: i used `swifter` library, and, i found in the library: there is `    case .json(let object):
              guard JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(object) else {
                throw SerializationError.invalidObject
              }
              let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object)
              return (data.count, {
                try $0.write(data)
              })`
So, i need pass `guard JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(object)`

Comment: You need to pass a JSON, not jsonData

Comment: So, How I can get `JSON` ?

Comment: Please don't add extra questions to an existing question, just ask another question.

Comment: @Abizern, Yes, I will sovle